# Find a record between 2 dates & If not found return the record with the smallest date

Tags: sql

I have a table like

```
Name       DateOfBirth
--------------------------------
Ramesh     17/04/1983

Pavan      16/03/1980

Rakesh     18/03/1975

Nadeem     19/05/1974

Kalam      20/08/2973
```

I'm writing a SP whose pseudo code is given below:

I'm passing a date to this SP as an input parameter

1. If @InputDate is found, the SP should return the record
2. If @InputDate is smaller than the smallest date in the table then the record with the smallest date should be returned
3. If @InputDate is not found but it is between the smallest & largest values in the column then the record which would fall immediately later should be returned

   - Is it possible to write the logic in a single statement?
   - The most optimized way to accomplish this task

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: any database will do

Comment: When it comes to date/time many dbms are far from ANSI SQL compliant...

Answer (score 2):

I think the query below (in MySQL) delivers what you want:

```
SELECT Name, DateOfBirth
FROM mytable
WHERE DateOfBirth >= @mydate
ORDER BY DateOfBirth LIMIT 1
```

**Case 1**, Input:

```
@mydate = '1972-03-16'
```

Output:

```
Name,   DateOfBirth
-------------------
Nadeem, 1974-05-19
```

**Case 2**, Input:

```
@mydate = '1980-03-16'
```

Output:

```
Name,   DateOfBirth
-------------------
Pavan,  1980-03-16
```

**Case 3**, Input:

```
@mydate = '1982-03-16'
```

Output:

```
Name,    DateOfBirth
-------------------
Ramesh,  1983-04-17
```

**Case 4**, Input:

```
@mydate = '2982-03-16'
```

Output:

```
Name,    DateOfBirth
-------------------
No records returned
```

Comment: Nice - and this can be translated pretty easily into other variants of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. First, let's see how you can get the records having minimum and maximum dates of your set:

**Min**:

```
select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth
```

**Max**:

```
select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth desc
```

This is how you get the **matching record**:

```
select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
where DateOfBirth = @InputDate
```

Now, let's get everything together into a query:

```
select mymin.Name as myminName, mymin.DateOfBirth as myminDateOfBirth,
       mymax.Name as mymaxName, myMax.DateOfBirth as mymaxDateOfBirth,
       therecord.Name as therecordName, therecord.DateOfBirth as therecordDateOfBirth
from
(select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth) mymin
join
(select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth desc) mymax
on 1 = 1
left join yourtable therecord
on therecord.DateOfBirth = @InputDate
```

As you can see, we can `select` all the possible values. The last step is to modify the selection to get only the `Name` and `DateOfBirth` of the desirable record. If there is no match and the date is not smaller than the minimum and not bigger than the maximum, then `null`s will be returned. For this purpose we need to use `case`-`when` syntax, like this:

```
select case (therecord.Name is null)
When 1 then (case mymin.DateOfBirth > @InputDate when 1 then mymin.Name
             else case mymax.DateOfBirth < @InputDate when 1 then mymax.Name else null end)
Else therecord.Name
End as Name,
case (therecord.Name is null)
When 1 then (case mymin.DateOfBirth > @InputDate when 1 then mymin.DateOfBirth
             else case mymax.DateOfBirth < @InputDate when 1 then mymax.DateOfBirth else null end)
Else therecord.DateOfBirth
End as DateOfBirth
from
(select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth) mymin
join
(select top 1 Name, DateOfBirth
from yourtable
order by DateOfBirth desc) mymax
on 1 = 1
left join yourtable therecord
on therecord.DateOfBirth = @InputDate
```

I assumed you are using SQL Server.

Warning: None of the code was tested, if there are any typos, please, let me know.